# java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection

Tags: ejb, remote-access, ejb-3.1

Environment - EJB 3.1, Struts 2.2, Wildfly-10.1.0

From Struts 2.2 Action class, i am doing remote calls to a method of stateless session  bean. This method is returning `java.sql.Connection` object.

```
15:09:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8) java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYEJB0054: Failed to marshal EJB parameters
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:338)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:318)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:275)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:184)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
15:09:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:138)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.getConnection(Unknown Source)
15:09:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at tod.ss.tasm.aehcs.struts2.MyAction.RetrieveOracleConnection(TestAction.java:428)
15:09:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:09:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15:09:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:09:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
15:09:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
15:09:40,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8) Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
15:09:40,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:253)
15:09:40,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:128)
15:09:40,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:335)
15:09:40,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)         ... 116 more
```

why this error occurs while returning `java.sql.Connection` object from EJB3 session bean to Struts 2.1 Action Class on remote calls? and what will be solution to solve this?

Comment: Because it isn't serializable, I guess.

Comment: @Aleksandr M ... EJB3.1 spec, section 3.2.3 -- "The objects that are passed as parameters on remote calls must be serializable." So how will i return  'java.sql.Connection' object to struts2 action claas.

Comment: What are you going to do with a remote sql connection instance?

Answer (score -2):

Check if you are using both datasource connection and external jdbc thin client connection. Try removing the connection fetched via thin client.just give a try.